# Sales Path feature for other Objects and for Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-experience

I am working on a POC, where we need to create a community to have the sales path type of navigation for various stages of the software development life cycle and in the guidance have the links to various documents like FRD document for Requirements Analysis phase, TDD for Design phase etc. Also, when all the necessary documents for a particular phase are completed then only move the status to next phase. For example, only when FRD is done and uploaded, then only the user/team can move the status to Design from Requirement Analysis .

As Sales Path feature is available only for Lead and Opportunity object, so for this requirement we cannot use Sales Path.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality ? Any pointers for this will be really helpful.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately, not on every Standard objects, Cases and Accounts are not supported for example... :(

Comment: Case has support processes which can be used to drive the actions on it which could be used rather than sales path.

Answer (score 6):

There are Ideas to rename Salespath to Path and make it available for any Object:

- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DvTRAA0
- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DicOAAS

I found this link to a slidedeck about the Lightning roadmap

- https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/partnerforce/roadmap-lightning-updates-november-3-2016

It basically says under safeharbor that Path will be available in Spring17 for Custom Objects and in Summer17 for the remaining other Standard Objects.

So it looks like waiting is better than build your own implementation.

I can't say for sure that it will be available in Community.

However with Lightning Components or even Visualforce you could do it yourself immediately. But doing it in high quality might take you some effort.

There are also other people trying that already. You might want to check this out:

- https://github.com/mshanemc/AnythingPath
- http://www.minerva18.com/blog/dynamic-reusable-lightning-design-status-visual-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 2):

This is now available with Summer17 update

1. Go to setup
2. type "Path Settings" in quick find box
3. Enable path settings
4. Click new path
5. Select Path Name, Object,Picklist

You will be able to define path as for the standard objects

Answer (score 0):

**If you can't see Path component in the section ..**

From the All Communities page in Setup, click Builder next to the community name.
Click on settings -> Advance options -> Enable Show all components to see all components in component section.

[image]